# Daily challenge not showing

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

Today I traveled to a friend's house and installed Binding of Isaac: Rebirth to play the daily challenge (to get the 31 consecutive daily challenges achievment).

However, the daily challenge is not showing up, as you can see below:

[image: no daily challenge]

Is there anything I can do? The internet signal is weak, but I can use it anyway (I am using it to send this).

Comment: Could it be that you only get the daily run the next day? I have no idea, but maybe tomorrow it is there.

Comment: It wasn't there anyway. I came back home and it was normal. Since I heard that the achiev doesnt need to be consecutive, I am fine.

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you have any mods on. Try to disabling them on the mods page by pressing Tab on the Keyboard or X on the controller.